# Web service response is coming up with different results when run in Jdeveloper and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web-services, wsdl, cxf, jdeveloper

I am experiencing data issues with Web service response when run in JDeveloper. In JDeveloper, The service runs ok, I get the response, no errors but certain data, specially object type in response is incorrect. To be precise list and sets of custom object types are coming up as empty. And strangely this happens only in JDeveloper. No data discrepancies when run in Eclipse.

Issue description in details: I generated a web service consumer/client code from a wsdl in Eclipse. I selected apache-cxf-2.7.12 as implementation. Code generated fine and I can call the generated web service client code and get the expected results without any issues in Eclipse.

Then I exported the generated web service client code into a jar and added to my java web project in JDeveloper 12c. I can call web service from a class in JDeveloper without any issues but the return object is coming up with incorrect data. I am not sure whats going on.

Here are the logs when run from Eclipse and JDeveloper. As you see, size of myList (list) is 1 when run in Eclipse and 0 when run in JDeveloper. Field1 is a string. It is returned correctly both in JDev and Eclipse.

```
    Begin main -- from Eclipse

Begin callWebService
Oct 09, 2014 2:18:13 PM org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromWSDL
INFO: Creating Service {http://server.edit.abc.com/}MyProcessImplService from WSDL: file:/C:/Users/johnDoe001/workspace/test1DynWebProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/wsdl/Edit.wsdl
response : field1: 2010331288
response : ************SIZE OF MYLIST: 1 *******************************
End callWebService  
End main
```

From JDeveloper 12c:

```
    Begin main  -- from JDeveloper

Begin callWebService
response: field1: 2010331288 
response: ************SIZE OF MYLIST: 0 *******************************
End callWebService


End main
```

Comment: Is there some error we're supposed to be seeing here?

Comment: I don't see any errors. Code is wrapped in try/catch

Comment: Primitive data types in the response are showing up fine but not the objects, list etc.

Comment: You should be prepared to do a whole bunch of logging, not just within your application but outside. First, [enable JVM-level logging](https://metro.java.net/nonav/1.2/guide/Logging.html). What application server is the webservice hosted on? Are the two IDEs communicating with the exact same web service deployment? Why is JDeveloper missing the standard CXF log output ("Creating web service endpoint...." etc)?

Comment: Thanks. Both the IDEs are communicating with the exact same web service deployment. I have verified it. I am using Tomcat for eclipse and Weblogic for JDeveloper. Please note that I tested the client code in both the IDEs by running a class as 'Java Application', not on the server.

Comment: I would look to the SOAP-logging to confirm exactly what's hitting the wire in both directions, before looking at any other moving parts. If I understand what you've posted here correctly, all that is still in-app log statements. You need a somewhat neutral perspective in the netherworld of the JVM between client and service. Also consider running the client *outside* the IDE (with a vanilla `main` method)

Comment: Make sure you have the same versions of JRE and apache-cxf in both environments (Eclipse and JDeveloper).

Comment: why are we not seeing the "Oct 09, 2014 2:18:13 PM org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromWSDL" line on the JDeveloper. Are you missing apache-cxf in your JDeveloper environment?

Comment: I am using the same version of JRE for both the IDEs. I have configured Eclipse to use apache-cxf but did not do that in JDeveloper. I ran the program as a class in Jdeveloper. So, I am not sure if I need to add or configure any apache cxf libraries in JDeveloper. If yes, what apache-cxf libraries I need and how can I pass them to a simple class with a main for testing?

Comment: @gmarintes, I created a rest web service client and it works fine both in Jdeveloper and Eclipse. That's is my workaround for now! Eclipse has Apache Cxf run time configuration in the IDE. I think it adds the cxf libraries to the classpath even if you run the client code/class as an application. I have not done any similar setup or added any cxf libraries to my project in JDeveloper. Probably that's why I don't see "ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromWSD" when the client code is run in Jdeveloper.

Comment: ....continue.....I am not sure though because I don't see any errors during the runtime in JDeveloper. The code runs fine. I get primitive data but not custom object type in the web service response. What apache cxf libraries are needed to run a client/consumer code?

Comment: What apache cxf libraries are needed to run a client/consumer code?